# IF Sentance in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I am building an automatic ranking on a game server and i have to do this by manipulating the MySQL database, this is not a strong knowledge area for me so ive tried to be a bit hacky with this.  i need to use the trigger function of SQL db.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ranking_up` AFTER UPDATE ON `highscore` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF NEW.score >= '10' and <= '100' THEN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET rankID=1 WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END IF;
IF NEW.score >= '100' and <= '300' THEN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET rankID=2 WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END IF;
IF NEW.score >= '300' THEN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET rankID=3 WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END IF;
END
```

I get the standard MySQL #1064 and i have tried to talk to my rubber duck... does not work it makes perfect sense for me but apparently does not work.

I am looking for the answer ofc BUT i also want to learn on my mistake here, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you setting delimiters? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: i have tried playing around with it but i get an exception right away and no explanation on why

Comment: You can't get away with NEW.score >= '10' and >= '100' you need to repeat new.score NEW.score >= '10' and new.score >= '100' , but this doesn't make a lot of sense since new.score >= 10 includes new.score >= 100 and why the quotes? Also your logic is wrong..eg first and second if will be executed if new.score >= 100

Comment: Perhaps first if should be if new score between 10 and 99 (etc)

Comment: True, ive messed up the logic with the >= ill edit  the question to fit what it should say.  id did just run a test with "between" idea but it did not work either

Comment: Why are you storing and comparing numbers as strings? That's really bad idea and a potential source of endless bugs and problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ive tried both. current version has numbers and not strings.

Comment: Then why are you comparing numbers with strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get away with NEW.score >= '10' and >= '100' you need to repeat new.score NEW.score >= '10' and new.score >= '100' . More digestibly you could use between if new.score is stored as an integer...

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `ranking_up` AFTER UPDATE ON `highscore` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF NEW.score between 10 and  99 THEN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET rankID=1 WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END IF;
IF NEW.score between 100 and 299 THEN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET rankID=2 WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END IF;
IF NEW.score >= 300 THEN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET rankID=3 WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END IF;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51PoUTCMAuWFoYaAz5ubW7/0

OR you could dispense with the ifs entirely and use case within the update statement.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `ranking_up` AFTER UPDATE ON `highscore` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


    UPDATE department_members
    SET RANK = 
     CASE 
        WHEN NEW.score between 10 and  99  THEN 1
        WHEN NEW.score between 100 and 299 THEN 2
        WHEN NEW.score >= 300 THEN 3
     END
     WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: tried in out and i still get "MySQL: #1064 - some thing wrong close to '$$ BEGIN IF NEW.score between 10 and 99 THEN UPDATE department_me"

Comment: The published link shows no error - is there any other tech in the mix?

Comment: the lower version jumps to error on row 9.

row 9 would refer to the "where" statement. 

should there not be an update for "department_members" to notfiy the script that we want to change table ? 

I am using MySql 5.0 and do my changes to thru phpMyAdmin.

Comment: ```` 
BEGIN
    UPDATE department_members
    SET department_members.rankID = 
     CASE 
        WHEN NEW.score between 1 and  99  THEN 1
        WHEN NEW.score between 100 and 299 THEN 2
        WHEN NEW.score >= 300 THEN 3
     END
     WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
END```
this worked perfect. it was the "SET RANK =" that broke the code. 
i did not need the delimiters så when editing the rank name to the correct value it worked! 

Thank you!